# Don't understand the constants provided in powertutor

Tags: android, constants

I was just going through powertutor source code and found many constants related to WiFi, CPU and LCD components. I can understand the flow but not getting about these constants.I am curious to know about this. Where these constants are derived from ? what are the standard values? etc.. Please point me to the link where I can get these information. Please do reply.

Update:

Following methods are in dreamConstants file. From where they got these constants? From which file they read it?

```
public double wifiHighPower() {
    return 720;
  }

  public double wifiLowHighTransition() {
    return 15;
  }

  public double wifiHighLowTransition() {
    return 8;
  }

  private static final double[] arrayWifiLinkRatios = {
    47.122645, 46.354821, 43.667437, 43.283525, 40.980053, 39.44422, 38.676581,
    34.069637, 29.462693, 20.248805, 11.034917, 6.427122
  };

  private static final double[] arrayWifiLinkSpeeds = {
    1, 2, 5.5, 6, 9, 11, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 54
  };
```

Comment: can you provide examples of those constants? [`/proc/cpuinfo`](http://www.linfo.org/proc_cpuinfo.html) and so on?

Comment: I updated he question please look through once.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the constants leading to the infos from the Proc/File system, they are often device-specific. Thus, you have to do it the hard way. Open a file browser, search in the file system for the constants and add them to the application.

As far as I know, that's is exactly what the developers of PowerTutor did. Some of these constrants are "common sense" but you cannot rely on that. There is always yet another device ...

Comment: I am not sure, what kind of class this is. If these constants represent the power consumption of the WiFi module I guess that they profiled the values using an external power meter. Otherwhise I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Those constants; for example 720 (mw) in the wifiHighPower function is the estimated power consumption which was measured on HTC G1. Actually, PowerTutor initially built a power model for HTC G1 only and it will caused high error rates on other phones. So, if u want to apply powertutor for yr phones, u need to build a new power model for your phone with the power modeling technique described in the PowerTutor's paper. Thus, u will get fitting constants for your phone instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @pokekarat. Try to use correct spelling and grammar; we want to make SO the first results when people search for technical questions, and this is less likely to happen if people use txtspk.